# go lang replace character in value

Tags: string, go, replace

I am using this below piece of the script, the value of "var1" returns `7d470821-a66a-5d57-b54f-2784ca96c591`, now, value that is assigned to  "var1", i want to remove "-" so that it becomes `7d470821a66a5d57b54f2784ca96c591`. I am trying below script

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

var namespace = uuid.NameSpaceURL
var value = "abc" + "hello world" + "bow"
var urls1 = []byte(value)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Generating UUIDs\n----------------")
    generate()
}

func generate() {
    //u, _ := uuid.NewUUID()
    //fmt.Println("UUID version 1:", u)
    var1 := uuid.NewSHA1(namespace, urls1)
    fmt.Println(var1 )
    var2 = strings.Replace(var1, "-","",0)
    fmt.Println(var2)   
}
```

and i am getting, please help me to correct what i am wrong.

```
./test-uuid1.go:23:29: cannot use var1 (variable of type uuid.UUID) as string value in argument to strings.Replace
```

Comment: The error says it all. `strings.Replace()` takes a string as first argument, and you are passing a UUID. You have to convert `var1` to a string if you want to use that method. To do that you need to change `var1` to `var1.String()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`strings.Replace()`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Replace) expects a `string`, and [`uuid.NewSHA1()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/uuid#NewSHA1) returns a value of type [`uuid.UUID`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/uuid#UUID).

Call its [`UUID.String()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/uuid#UUID.String) method to obtain a `string` representation.

Also note that passing `0` to `strings.Replace()` will perform 0 replaces, so nothing will be changed. Not too useful. Pass `-1` to indicate that you want to replace all occurrences of `-`, or even better, use [`strings.ReplaceAll()`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#ReplaceAll):

```
var2 := strings.ReplaceAll(var1.String(), "-", "")
```

(Note `var2` doesn't exist, so you must use `:=` [short variable declaration](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) instead of simple [assignment](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignment_statements).)

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/PEwDi6tvS32)):

```
Generating UUIDs
----------------
7d470821-a66a-5d57-b54f-2784ca96c591
7d470821a66a5d57b54f2784ca96c591
```